# How to name multiple rows on an AS statement in mySQL

Tags: mysql

Here is my statement:

```
SELECT MIN(OrderTotal), MAX(OrderTotal) FROM retail_order;
```

my output is:

```
MIN(OrderTotal)     MAX(OrderTotal)
310.00              480.00
```

My values are correct but I want to name the columns Minimum and the other Maximum not the defaults. how do I name both columns simultaneously? I tried using an AS statement but was given an error when trying to name them both. I was only able to name one column.

Comment: use alias name.

Answer (score 1):

Use alias to display column name as you want. `Alias`ing is used to create a temporary name for columns or tables.

```
SELECT MIN(OrderTotal) as Minimum, MAX(OrderTotal) as Maximum 
FROM retail_order;
```